# Injection and call a function in another program

Tags: c++, windows, dll, code-injection

Just for improve my knowledge. I want to call a function that located in a program (called Target) from my program (called My program).

**There're my steps:**

1. Injection my DLL into the Target program via Windows Hooks.
2. My program gets the CALLER function's address  in DLL through GetProcAddress, then, uses a function pointer to call it.
3. CALLER function will initilization a function pointer which points to a fixed address in the Target program.
4. And then, of course, call it. But this step (only this) makes My program crashes.

I want to know that Calling a function in another program like what I did is impossible? If it's impossible, what I was wrong?

Here's a few lines of code:

My program:

```
TargetThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hTargetWindow, &TargetProcessId);
hLib = LoadLibraryA(DLL_FILE);

pfSetHook = (pfSetHookType)GetProcAddress(hLib, "SetHook");
pfSetHook(hLib, TargetThreadId);
```

My Dll:

```
#define SHOWADDR 0x00401472
SetHook(HINSTANCE hLib, DWORD dwTargetThreadId)
{
     ghHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC)HookProc, hLib, dwTargetThreadId);
}
Caller()
{
     pfShowType pfShow = (pfShowType)SHOWADDR; // points to fixed address which was defined
     pfShow(); // calling
}
```

Target program:

```
// The function's address is 0x00401472
Show()
{
     MessageBoxA(NULL, "Yeah, I'm a function in Target :)!", "Show Function", 0);
}
```

And here's the disassembly code of the Target program

```
...
00401472  PUSH EBP
00401473  MOV EBP,ESP
00401475  SUB ESP,18
00401478  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+C],0
00401480  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8],Target.0040300>
00401488  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],Target.0040301>
00401490  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],0 
00401497  CALL <JMP.&USER32.MessageBoxA>
0040149C  SUB ESP,10
0040149F  LEAVE
004014A0  RETN
...
```

Comment: Please post code from your HookProc. BTW setting a WH_CBT hook just gives you some window messages (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So I think WH_CBT isn't the right choice, you should read about injection with CreateRemoteThread.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think my HookProc has problem. Because It works well. I just have a problem that when the function which in DLL calling to a fixed address, it makes my program be 'Ghost state'. If it doesn't make a call, everything's ok. You can read my steps above. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you make it clear what you have done, I doubt you'll get help. You've included only a portion of the relevant code. All you have is an executable, an injector, and a hook DLL. It's easy enough for you to include them all.

Comment: Is there any other way to include them? I don't think post all of codes is a good idea. Thanks.